# Model namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have User model with static method authenticate and I use Rubyoverflow gem.
In the controller I code:

```
User.authenticate(params[:user], params[:password])
```

but get the error:

> undefined method `authenticate' for
>   Rubyoverflow::User:Class

How can I say that I need the User from Rails model?

Comment: did you try ::User.authenticate ?

Comment: thanks. can you create the answer to give me ability to close questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 ::User.authenticate(params[:user], params[:password])
```